# Equivalent of ServletContextListener in vertx-mod-jersey

Tags: jersey, vert.x

When writing a web application in a servlet container, you can write a listener that implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener to do something when the ServletContext is initialized or destroyed.

How do you do the equivalent when writing an application for Jersey in Vert.x using vertx-mod-jersey?

Answer (score 0):

i never use ServletContextListener, just guess:

https://github.com/englishtown/vertx-jersey/blob/develop/ext-jersey%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fenglishtown%2Fvertx%2Fjersey%2Fimpl%2FDefaultJerseyServer.java#L103

there is a setupHandler you can do stuff you want to run before http server start
and you can override close method to do some teardown.

Answer (score 0):

In this implementation they use the RoutingContext of Vertx

https://github.com/politrons/Vertx-Spring-Jersey/blob/master/src/main/java/vertx/JerseyHandler.java